# Can't save data into MongoDB server using Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to integrate a database into my DiscordBot app and currently having a problem with inputting new user into MongoDB using Mongoose.
The console also show no err at all.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const User = require('../models/userModels')

module.exports = message => {
    User.findOne({userID:message.author.id}, (err,user)=>{
        if(user == null){ //Create new db collections if none was found
            const user = new User({
                _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
                userID: message.author.id,
                username: message.author.username,
                role: ["default"],
                balance: 0,
                level: 1,
                exp: 0,
                lastAttendance: message.createdAt
            })

            user.save()
            .then(result => {
                console.log(result)
                message.reply("Information saved")
            })
            .catch(err => console.log.err)

        }
}
```

This is my model code:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema

var userSchema = new Schema({
    _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    userID:{type: String, unique:true, required:true},
    username: String,
    balance:{type: Number, require:true},
    role: {type:String, enum: ['default','admin']},
    level:{type: Number, require:true},
    exp:{type: Number, require:true},
    lastAttendance: Date
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Users', userSchema)
```

Comment: could you `console.log(user)` before the if condition, to check if the user exists or not?
also `console.log(message.author)` to check its contents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you are not getting error logs is because of the `console.log` syntax in the `catch` statement is wrong. Change `console.log.err` to `console.log(err)`

The type defined for `role` in the `userSchema` is `String` and you are passing it as array `role: ["default"]`. You need to change this to `role: "default"`.

Also on success, if you are trying to set the key `reply` to the `message` object with value `"Information saved"` then you should replace `message.reply("Information saved")` with `message.reply = "Information saved"`

Comment: Problem solved, thanks!!
By the way, message.reply was a function from discord.js module, so I'm ok with that part